# How do I ask a comment on multiple answers?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

In my question [What does it mean to do MLE with a continuous variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154046/what-does-it-mean-to-do-mle-with-a-continuous-variable) at least two (and perhaps all three) answerers told me, essentially, that instead of looking at probability, I should be looking at probability density.

I don't understand why this is. If one person told me that I'd ask them to clarify the answer to explain it more, but I'm not sure what to do if I need the same clarification from multiple people. I don't want to clutter up the site with the same comment repeated over and over, but I also want a way of notifying all relevant parties I'd like clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either pick a person to ask clarification from or ask a follow-up question (and link to the other question).

Comment: Or just edit your question with the new information. That will bring it to the front page where, with any luck, one or more of the answerers will see it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes, but they might not re-read it properly.

Comment: @user, it seems to me that would also be an objection to Qiaochu's suggestions, no? But if people aren't going to read things properly, there's not much you can do, is there?

Comment: A follow-up question demands a re-read, while an edit can go unnoticed. I was presuming the edit would be a subtle one, merely editing what was already there. However, if the edit extended the post and didn't edit the old content (or did something else which the the answerers would notice) then this would work. Of course, after editing the post it requires little effort to inform the answerers that you have edited the question and can they have a look at it.

Comment: @user, an edit won't go unnoticed if it starts off with "EDIT: Some people have told me I should be looking at probability density, I hope they can explain why" or something like that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I can't speak for other people, but you certainly misunderestimate my ability to read things properly! I just read what I *think* is there, not what is there.